# How to solve an issue in a simple TR Tkinter program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Major programming noob here, and my very first question in stackoverflow. I'm trying to make a time reaction tester, with a simplistic Tkinter GUI.

Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import tkinter as tk
import time
import random

class TRTest(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid()
        self.canv()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.Test                 
        self.totalt = []

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitbtn = tk.Button(self, text = "Quit", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitbtn.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "TRTest")
        self.label.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        self.testbtn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start test", command = self.Test)
        self.testbtn.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        
    def canv(self):
        self.scrn = tk.Canvas(self, width = 400, height = 400, bg = "#E8E8E8")
        self.scrn.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    
    def fixate(self):
        self.scrn.create_line(190, 200, 210, 200, width = 2)
        self.scrn.create_line(200, 190, 200, 210, width = 2)
        
    def createCircle(self):
        self.scrn.create_oval(150, 150, 250, 250, fill = "red", tag = "circle")                
    
    def Test(self):              
        if len(self.totalt) == 0:
            self.fixate()                
            self.update()
            self.bind_all("<Key>", self.gettime)
        self.after(random.randint(1000, 5000))
        self.t0 = time.clock()
        self.createCircle()
        
    def gettime(self, event):
        t = time.clock() - self.t0
        self.totalt.append(t)
        self.scrn.delete("circle")
        if len(self.totalt) < 6:
            self.Test
        else:
            print(self.totalt)
a = tk.Tk()
b = TRTest(a)
b.mainloop()
```

It should be making 5 trials and returning the list of the measured TR times, but it freezes before showing a second circle. Where's the problem?

Comment: where is b.mainloop() defined?  Does it inherit that method?

Comment: @Patrick: `mainloop()` is a universal tkinter widget method in inherited from `tk.Frame`.

Comment: Matías: What do you want to happen after the red circle is displayed for each `Test` run? What reaction time is being measured (the time from what to what)?

Comment: The time it takes you to react, by pressing any key. @Terry Jan Reddy is correct I should display instructions to go from click to key input type. 
Any counseling or comment on code organization, refactoring, time optimization, pythonic implementation or whatever is very much appreciated! I'm so glad I can receive this kind of feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer from Patrick Haugh, you aren't using the .after method correctly.

Change this line of code

```
self.after(random.randint(1000, 5000))
```

to

```
self.after(random.randint(1000, 5000),self.Test)
```

and move it to after

```
if len(selftotalt) < 6:
```

This will call the self.Test function again after a random period of time between 1 and 5 seconds.
If more 6 or more reaction times have been captures it will no longer call the function again but print out the times.

Full code that seem to work for me

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random

class TRTest(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid()
        self.canv()
        self.createWidgets()                 
        self.totalt = []

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitbtn = tk.Button(self, text = "Quit", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitbtn.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "TRTest")
        self.label.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        self.testbtn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start test", command = self.Test)
        self.testbtn.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def canv(self):
        self.scrn = tk.Canvas(self, width = 400, height = 400, bg = "#E8E8E8")
        self.scrn.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    def fixate(self):
        self.scrn.create_line(190, 200, 210, 200, width = 2)
        self.scrn.create_line(200, 190, 200, 210, width = 2)

    def createCircle(self):
        self.scrn.create_oval(150, 150, 250, 250, fill = "red", tag = "circle")                

    def Test(self):              
        if len(self.totalt) == 0:
            self.fixate()                
            self.update()
            self.bind_all("<Key>", self.gettime)

        self.t0 = time.clock()
        self.createCircle()

    def gettime(self, event):
        t = time.clock() - self.t0
        self.totalt.append(t)
        self.scrn.delete("circle")
        if len(self.totalt) < 6:
            self.after(random.randint(1000, 5000),self.Test)
        else:
            print(self.totalt)
a = tk.Tk()
b = TRTest(a)
b.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works mostly.  @Matias, does this answer your question?  Enhancements: instruction -- I did not know to change from mouse to key entry until I looked at code.  Response to immediate initial circle should be deleted.  Recording and printing should stop after 5 real responses and average, sd added.  Currently, keys after 5 extend and print again.  Last output: `[111.53977929833644, 0.3603251623629262, 0.41193483472277137, 0.2408621481522033, 0.2699220817867598, 0.3428859435493905, 17.526888331573872, 18.054828033341323, 276.85476857866433]`.  Output should go to GUI.

Comment: You're right, those things are next, but I'm working by steps. Thank you greatly scotty and Teddy, I very much appreciate being able to get some help.
(The first thing to appear should be the fixation cross, going to fix that now)

Comment: Done. This wasn't the ultimate solution as it still had an issue, but it helped a lot nonetheless. The last and improving version: https://github.com/Cerebrock/TRTest

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run the method `Test` with

```
self.Test
```

Try instead

```
self.Test()
```

Comment: That's only a (small) part of the problem.

Comment: I'm all ears @martineau! :)

Comment: @Matías: Then answer _my_ question in the last comment I made under your question. We need to know in detail what you want the program to do.